# Select the next nan value in a row and column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently dealing with an excel data like this:

In this case, I'd like to create a dataframe for each of the table, which starts from the word 'calculation' and ends in the next blank column and a blank row. Furthermore, the given data is not properly positioned, so that it can be positioned everywhere along the excel file, and the length of the columns and rows will not be the same for each table. But it will always start with 'Calculation' word and ends with a blank column on the right and a blank row line on the bottom

[image]

Comment: @anky_91 Do you know how to show an excel data so that it can be shown in a more clear way in this group?

Comment: How do you want to read them,, I mean when you want to read from the 2nd line just skip the first row using `skiprows` but I doubt you can read such an excel as shown in the picture as different dataframes. Its best to do some preprocessing first :)

Comment: I'd like to create a dataframe that starts from each 'Calculation' Words (in picture above that means the 2nd row and the 2nd, 10th, and 19th column) and ends with the first blank column (means the 8th column and the 17th column) and also ends with the blank row lines in the bottom (can't be shown as data is long). 

My first thougth was to use the .iloc function with some boundary (e.g `df.iloc [first row of 'Calculation : First blank row, First column of 'Calculation' : First blank column]` But it somehow didn't work properly

Comment: Sorry by not mentioning @anky_91